# Popover displaying at top of long user input form in tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uipopovercontroller

I've looked at many questions and answers about this but none seem to fit what I'm doing.

I have a rather long user input form I made with a table view (the labels and textviews for the questions are in table cells) and I need to fire popovers when the user clicks a textview that has a multiselect option (like a dropdownlist).  The popover seems to be presenting from the top of the tableviewcontroller and I'm not sure how to calculate where to place it so it's over the textview that was clicked in the cell.  There can be multiple textviews in the cells so I'd rather not present the popover when the cell is selected which seems like it could be an option.

Right now when I click a textview at the bottom of the form the popover isn't even visible.  I know I can find the right rect with trial and error on hard coding bounds, but there has to be a way to calculate this consistently.

I fire the popover like this:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    Boolean returnVal = YES;
    if(self.popOverController == nil){

        switch(textField.tag)
        {
            case 1:
                 [self fireDisciplinePopOver:[textField bounds]];
                returnVal = NO;
                break;

             case 2:  
                 etc...

             default:
                break;
        }
    }
    return returnVal;
}


-(void)fireDisciplinePopOver:(CGRect)rect
{
    UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle: nil];
    ICAMDisciplineTableViewController *popoverTable = (ICAMDisciplineTableViewController*)[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"DisciplineController"];
    self.popOverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc]initWithContentViewController:popoverTable];
    self.popOverController.delegate = self;
    popoverTable.delegate = self;
    [self.popOverController presentPopoverFromRect:rect inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used a segue to present a popover. The segue includes an anchor view for the popover. All I did was anchor the popover there. I think this should work for you.